# UIDatePicker Apple Bug on iOS 14 with TimeZones?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, uidatepicker

## Bug

`UIDatePicker` on iOS 14 presents a bug with specific timezones when changing the month scroll wheel - and does not update the month value correctly.

## Playground Code

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        picker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
        picker.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Pacific/Auckland")
        picker.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        picker.date = Date()
        picker.addTarget(self,
                         action:#selector(MyViewController.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        view.addSubview(picker)
        
        self.view = view
    }
    
    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        print("value: \(picker.date)")
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

## Repro Steps

If you don’t set the TZ, **it works as expected**, shows the correct month selected on expand, changes month as you scroll wheel.

If you set the TZ to `"America/Denver"` — **it works**. Heck, if you set it to `"BOO"` — it works (defaulting back to current, I believe).

However, if you set the TZ to `"Pacific/Auckland"` (New Zealand) **it borks** — expanding months show September, and **doesn’t change the month when you switch from October to September (stays October).**

[image: Screenshot]

### Other relevant details:

- Manually setting my computer to NZ timezone and using default timezone for the picker, the month picker **works as expected**.

Initially, I thought it had something to do with our app users being able to set a user profile timezone, allowing their timezone to be set to something different than their current locale/timezone from the iOS device. Then isolated to the Playground above still presents the same bug.

--

Anyone else experiencing this? Am I missing something silly, or should I file a Radar?

Comment: Tried your code on XCode 12.0.1 playground, I cannot seem to reproduce the issue you mentioned. It shows up in October and I can change to September

Comment: Yeah, @Bill I'm on Xcode 12.1. Even tried switching my computer timezone to another timezone and the same result. However, if I switch my computer's device to NZ timezone, and use the current timezone as NZ or manually set the TZ to NZ, it works in both cases...

Comment: i've confirmed this behavior with Xcode 12.1 using "Pacific/Aukland" timezone and found further evidence that there's something funky going on here. selecting any month in the month/year scroll wheel, returning to the calendar, then back into the month/year should show that there is a discrepancy between the scroll wheel and the month/year "dropdown" button. in fact, just scroll through the months and years and watch that button skip months.

Comment: further testing in Xcode 12.2 beta 3 seems to indicate that the bug experienced in previous versions of Xcode 12 might have been fixed.